# jquery .each does not work on ready

Tags: jquery, css, each, document-ready

I want to make visibility hidden some elements that have the same class. I tried to do the code below but it does not work as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radio').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('style', 'visibility:hidden')
    })
})
```

I would like to make this works on load so the user can not see the elements I want to hide.

This code works as expected when I paste it in the console.

Anykind of help will bemuch appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/danvim/zs302q03/ Your code works. Have you checked the fact that you correctly included jQuery?

Comment: Then you don't want document ready do you?

Comment: Yes I did because other script works

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Did you check your console? Was there any error? Are the `.radio` added dynamically?

Comment: Arent you using ajax to load `.radio`?

Comment: "*I would like to make this [work] on load*" - on load of *what*? The page, the new elements, are you using [tag:ajax]? Are you updating the `style` of the element(s) using the `css()` method, later? Is there anything else in the `style` attribute that you need to preserve, or that's overwritten through the use of `attr()`, later? Can you reproduce your problem ("[MCVE]," showing the problematic scenario, because the posted jQuery should certainly work as written)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use attribute but css()

```
$(this).css("visibility ", "hidden");
```

Comment: OP's code actually works, so your answer should just be a comment.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski can you try ``console.log($(this));`` and check if anything appears in the console on load? Also can you post a link to the site maybe? Since it should work technically speaking. Also each is not needed, you can replace .each() with .css() directly.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.radio').each(function (key,value) {
        $(this).css({'visibility':'hidden'})
    })
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/v4h2534p/)

Comment: did you try what I am telling you  ? @Stanislas Piotrowski. is it working for you or not ? just let us know if you have any issue...

Answer (score -1):

you can just use this simple code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.radio').attr('style','visibility:hidden')
})
```